# Error: Cannot find symbol variable

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I watched a tutorial from this guy:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SUvA1fXaKw

At the end (about 9:55) he wrote down:

```
if(fragment != null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
        ft.commit();
```

I renamed my content_main in activity_main_menu1_start_seite and I thought I could just replace the content_main with activity_main_menu1_start_seite, but then it says "cannot find Symbol variable activity_main_menu1_start_seite"

Maybe you Need my whole Code.
I marked you the error as the Blockquote.
Sorry for any issues (I am new to this site)

```
package com.d_and_d_studios.test3;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import at.markushi.ui.CircleButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

   CircleButton btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        btn = (CircleButton) findViewById(R.id.circleButton);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //Brauche ich vielleicht doch noch irgendwann!
    //@Override
    //public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
         // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
         // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
       // int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
         //if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            //return true;
        //}

        //return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    //}

    private void displaySelectedScreen(int id) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_powersavingmode:
                fragment = new Menu_2_Energiesparmodus();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_feedback:
                fragment = new Menu_3_Bewerte_die_App();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_send:
                fragment = new Menu_4_Teile_uns_Fehler_mit();

        }
```

> if(fragment != null) {
>                   FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
>                   ft.replace(R.id.activity_main_menu1_start_seite, fragment);
>                   ft.commit();
>               }

```
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_powersavingmode) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_feedback) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        displaySelectedScreen(id);
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.d_and_d_studios.test3.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/toolbar_main">

    <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
        android:id="@+id/circleButton"
        android:layout_width="116dp"
        android:layout_height="116dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_power_settings_new_black_24dp"
        app:cb_color="#000"
        app:cb_pressedRingWidth="20dp"

        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="178dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/menu1_text1"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.23" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your XML file as well?

Comment: sure if i knew how... The Code is to long

Comment: It doesn't matter how long the code is, just copy the whole code and paste it here like you posted your Java Classes. Edit your question and paste the code of XML file.

Comment: i added th XML file now

Comment: what is the name of this XML class?

Answer (score 1):

The `R` class is generated based on the names and content of files in the `res` subfolder of your project. If Android Studio does not do this automatically, you can force a manual build by clicking the Build button on the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Which xml contains an ID of `activity_main_menu1_start_seite`?

Renaming the XML file only affects the `R.layout` values, and `include` tags in the other xml files.

If it can't find `R.id.activity_main_menu1_start_seite`, then nothing contains `android:id` with that name. Specifically, you need a ViewGroup (such as a FrameLayout) within `activity_main_drawer.xml` with that value